# Flex error negative range in character class

Tags: regex, flex-lexer

I am writing a parser using Flex and Bison and have defined various tokens as:

```
[0-9]+          { yylval.str=strdup(yytext); return digit; }

[0-9]+\.[0-9]*      { yylval.str=strdup(yytext); return floating; }

[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*  { yylval.str=strdup(yytext);  return key; }

[a-zA-Z/][a-zA-Z_-/.]*  { yylval.str=strdup(yytext);  return string; }

[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+     { yylval.str=strdup(yytext);  return hostname; }

["][a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*()_-+=.,/?]* { yylval.str=strdup(yytext);  return qstring1; }

[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*()_-+=.,/?]*["] { yylval.str=strdup(yytext);  return qstring2; }

[#].+           { yylval.str=strdup(yytext);  return comment;}

[ \n\t]         {} /* Ignore white space. */

.           {printf("ERR:L:%d\n", q); return ERROR;}
```

And it shows an error "Negative Range in Character Class" in the regexps for string, qstring1 and qstring2.

Can someone please help me with where I went wrong?

The spec is that:
Non quoted strings may contain ASCII alphanumeric characters, underscores, hyphens, forward slash and period and must start with letter or slash.

Quoted strings may contain any alphanumeric character between the quotes.

I have taken two different strings for quoted strings for some more specifications to be fulfilled.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

For (`string`, `qstring1`, `qstring2`) you need to either place the hyphen (`-`) as the **first** or **last** character of your character class `[]` or just simply escape it `\-` if elsewhere.

- (string)

  ```
  [a-zA-Z/][a-zA-Z_./-]*
  ```
- (qstring1)

  ```
  ["][a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*()_+=.,/?-]*
  ```
- (qstring2)

  ```
  [a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*()_+=.,/?-]*["]
  ```

Answer (score 2):

`-` needs to be escaped with a backslash.
For qstring1, try the following:

```
["][a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*()_\-+=.,/?]*
```

Comment: The slash doesn't need to be escaped.

Comment: I guess it depends on the regex compiler. I tested it on Ruby.

Comment: It depends only if the slash is used as delimiter, but the slash is not special character inside or outside a character class.

Answer (score 0):

I guess while writing a regular expression you should always write it with it's priority order :
for example for this line of code :
`[+-/*><=]  {printf("Operator %c\n",yytext[0]); return yytext[0];}` won't give any error.
whereas :
`[+-*/><=]        {printf("Operator %c\n",yytext[0]); return yytext[0];}` will.
hope it helps.

Comment: Wrong guess. The first will give the same error as the second. Don't post guesswork here. Priority has nothing to do with it.