# I'm getting an error saying, NEGATIVE RANGE IN CHARACTER CLASS in lines 15,17 and 19

Tags: lex

Please find the error in lines 15,17 and 19:

```
%{
#include<stdio.h>
int c=0;
FILE *fp;
%}
operator [+-*/]
identifier [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*
number [0-9]+
expression ({identifier}|{number}){operator}({identifier}|{number})
%%
\n { c++; }
^"#".+ ;
^("int "|"float "|"char ").+ ;
"void main()" ;
{identifier}"="({expression}+";") {printf("Valid arithmetic expression       in line %d",c+1);ECHO;printf("\n");}

{identifier}"="({number}|{identifier}";") {printf("Valid assignment statement in line %d",c+1);ECHO;printf("\n");}

({number}|([0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*))"="{expression}+ {printf("Invalid: rules for naming identifier are violated in line %d",c+1);ECHO;printf("\n");}

{identifier}"=;" {printf("Invalid right side of expression missing in   line %d",c+1);ECHO;printf("\n");}

{operator}{operator}+ {printf("Invalid multiple operators cannot occur consecutively in line %d",c+1);ECHO;printf("\n");}  
. ;
%%
main()
{
yyin=fopen("3b.txt","r");
yylex();
fclose(yyin);
}
```

Comment: Please provide the line numbers too. Or just mark them in the code. That might interest someone to look into your problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23416662/flex-error-negative-range-in-character-class

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that your error "Negative Range in Character Class" is actually on lines 15, 17, or 19.  I believe that it is on line 6.  Your code says `operator [+-*/]`, by which you appear to mean "the symbols `+`, `-`, `*`, and `/`".

However, the `-` is actually being interpreted as a "range" from `+` to `*`. Since `+` is character 43 and `*` is character 42, that range is backwards.

If you escape the `-` with `\` before it, you should not have that error anymore.