# Negative range in character class in flex

Tags: c, flex-lexer, lex

So when I try to run my flex file that contains the following piece of code, I get the error "negative range in character class." It identifies an error at line 65 which is the print statement in this segment of code. Would anyone know how to fix this? Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

```
[+-*(),/^] {
        printf("Token and Lexeme: %s\n", yytext);
        /*
        return *yytext;
        */
       }
```

Comment: You need to put the `-` first when inside `[]`, otherwise it is treated as defining a range, e.g. `[a-z]`. Or else escape it.

Comment: Duplicate of [Flex error negative range in character class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23416662/flex-error-negative-range-in-character-class).